# Updating dataframe column names based on values given in another dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am very new to python. I am trying to rename the columns of a data frame based on another dataframe.

Essentially My data looks like

DataFrame1

```
A    B    C   D
1    2    3   4
```

I have another table that looks like this' DataFrame2

```
Col1    Col2
A       E
B       Q
C       R
D       Z
```

I want to rename the columns of my first data frame based on this table so that it will come out: Note. The columns name order are not same.

```
E    Q    R    Z
1    2    3    4
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use map with get by setting index i.e

```
df.columns = df.columns.map(df2.set_index('Col1')['Col2'].get)

   E  Q  R  Z
0  1  2  3  4
```

Answer (score 5):

Use `rename` by dictionary created by `zip`:

```
d = dict(zip(df1['Col1'], df1['Col2']))
df = df.rename(columns=d)
print (df)
   E  Q  R  Z
0  1  2  3  4
```

Comment: @Dark - I am confued who give me vote up ;) So plus 1